How to group features and write a custom "similarity calculating function"? How to approach it?
I am trying to learn how I should go about crafting a "similarity calculating function", which will compute the similarity between two consonants or consonant clusters. This current question you're reading isn't how to actually practically solve that problem, but it's about the general approach I should go about for crafting a similarity calculating function for such a problem.
One approach (after many iterations of learning), is to have:

Groups of features (not just binary 1/0 features), which can get arbitrary integer values perhaps.
Global weights on each feature group.
A weightedCosineSimilarity function, which calculates the similarity, multiplying by the global feature group weights.

Sort of like this:
// Define weights for each feature
const FEATURE_WEIGHTS = [
  0.4,  // Place of articulation
  0.4,  // Manner of articulation
  0.2   // Voicing
];

function weightedCosineSimilarity(a: number[], b: number[]): number {
  let weightedDotProduct = 0;
  let weightedMagnitudeA = 0;
  let weightedMagnitudeB = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    const weight = FEATURE_WEIGHTS[i];
    weightedDotProduct += weight * a[i] * b[i];
    weightedMagnitudeA += weight * a[i] * a[i];
    weightedMagnitudeB += weight * b[i] * b[i];
  }

  return weightedDotProduct / (Math.sqrt(weightedMagnitudeA) * Math.sqrt(weightedMagnitudeB));
}

// Example usage
const consonants: Record<string, number[]> = {
  'p': [0, 0, 0],  // Bilabial plosive, unvoiced
  'b': [0, 0, 1],  // Bilabial plosive, voiced
  'm': [0, 1, 1],  // Bilabial nasal, voiced
  't': [1, 0, 0],  // Alveolar plosive, unvoiced
};

// Compare some consonants
const pairs = [['p', 'b'], ['p', 'm'], ['p', 't']];
pairs.forEach(([c1, c2]) => {
  const similarity = weightedCosineSimilarity(consonants[c1], consonants[c2]);
  console.log(`Weighted similarity between ${c1} and ${c2}: ${similarity.toFixed(2)}`);
});

// For comparison, let's also show the unweighted similarity
function unweightedCosineSimilarity(a: number[], b: number[]): number {
  const dotProduct = a.reduce((sum, _, i) => sum + a[i] * b[i], 0);
  const magnitudeA = Math.sqrt(a.reduce((sum, val) => sum + val * val, 0));
  const magnitudeB = Math.sqrt(b.reduce((sum, val) => sum + val * val, 0));
  return dotProduct / (magnitudeA * magnitudeB);
}

pairs.forEach(([c1, c2]) => {
  const similarity = unweightedCosineSimilarity(consonants[c1], consonants[c2]);
  console.log(`Unweighted similarity between ${c1} and ${c2}: ${similarity.toFixed(2)}`);
});

But quickly I can see cases in my imagination where two unrelated consonants get the same weighted value. It is not really taking into account the index, and it is just calculating a number of the vector, and two vectors might have the same number but be unrelated. Isn't that an obvious problem with this approach? It seems like it to me, but I don't know for sure that is the case.
Another approach is crafting a completely custom "similarity" function, sort of like this:
// Define more detailed phonetic features
type PhoneticFeatures = {
  place: 'bilabial' | 'labiodental' | 'dental' | 'alveolar' | 'postalveolar' | 'palatal' | 'velar' | 'uvular' | 'glottal';
  manner: 'plosive' | 'nasal' | 'trill' | 'tap' | 'fricative' | 'lateral' | 'approximant' | 'affricate';
  voiced: boolean;
  aspirated: boolean;
};

const consonants: Record<string, PhoneticFeatures> = {
  'p': { place: 'bilabial', manner: 'plosive', voiced: false, aspirated: false },
  'b': { place: 'bilabial', manner: 'plosive', voiced: true, aspirated: false },
  'm': { place: 'bilabial', manner: 'nasal', voiced: true, aspirated: false },
  't': { place: 'alveolar', manner: 'plosive', voiced: false, aspirated: false },
  'd': { place: 'alveolar', manner: 'plosive', voiced: true, aspirated: false },
  'n': { place: 'alveolar', manner: 'nasal', voiced: true, aspirated: false },
  // Add more consonants as needed
};

function advancedPhoneticSimilarity(a: PhoneticFeatures, b: PhoneticFeatures): number {
  let similarity = 0;

  // Place of articulation similarity
  const placeOrder = ['bilabial', 'labiodental', 'dental', 'alveolar', 'postalveolar', 'palatal', 'velar', 'uvular', 'glottal'];
  const placeDifference = Math.abs(placeOrder.indexOf(a.place) - placeOrder.indexOf(b.place));
  const placeSimularity = 1 - (placeDifference / (placeOrder.length - 1));
  similarity += placeSimularity * 0.4; // Weight for place of articulation

  // Manner of articulation similarity
  const mannerGroups = [
    ['plosive', 'affricate'],
    ['fricative', 'approximant'],
    ['nasal', 'lateral'],
    ['trill', 'tap']
  ];
  let mannerSimilarity = a.manner === b.manner ? 1 : 0;
  if (mannerSimilarity === 0) {
    for (const group of mannerGroups) {
      if (group.includes(a.manner) && group.includes(b.manner)) {
        mannerSimilarity = 0.5;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  similarity += mannerSimilarity * 0.3; // Weight for manner of articulation

  // Voicing similarity
  const voicingSimilarity = a.voiced === b.voiced ? 1 : 0;
  similarity += voicingSimilarity * 0.2; // Weight for voicing

  // Aspiration similarity
  const aspirationSimilarity = a.aspirated === b.aspirated ? 1 : 0;
  similarity += aspirationSimilarity * 0.1; // Weight for aspiration

  return similarity;
}

// Compare some consonants
const pairs = [['p', 'b'], ['p', 'm'], ['p', 't'], ['t', 'd'], ['m', 'n']];
pairs.forEach(([c1, c2]) => {
  const similarity = advancedPhoneticSimilarity(consonants[c1], consonants[c2]);
  console.log(`Advanced similarity between ${c1} and ${c2}: ${similarity.toFixed(2)}`);
});

// Additional function to demonstrate how this could be used with machine learning approaches
function phoneticFeaturesToVector(features: PhoneticFeatures): number[] {
  const placeOrder = ['bilabial', 'labiodental', 'dental', 'alveolar', 'postalveolar', 'palatal', 'velar', 'uvular', 'glottal'];
  const mannerOrder = ['plosive', 'nasal', 'trill', 'tap', 'fricative', 'lateral', 'approximant', 'affricate'];
  
  return [
    placeOrder.indexOf(features.place) / (placeOrder.length - 1),
    mannerOrder.indexOf(features.manner) / (mannerOrder.length - 1),
    features.voiced ? 1 : 0,
    features.aspirated ? 1 : 0
  ];
}

But is that any better? Won't it run into the same problem?
Basically the crux of my question/problem is, how do the numbers need to be distributed amongst the different consonant vectors? Does it matter if two vectors of unrelated consonants sum or multiply to the same value? Is it important to somehow take the index of the feature into account? Stuff like that.
How do I know in advance that the road I'm traveling down, that the solution I'm about to implement, for calculating similarity between consonants or consonant clusters, will result in something where it's like "yeah, these values look just about what I was intuitively thinking".
There is a big disconnect for me as to how I can go from the desire to compute similarity between consonant clusters, to actually running an algorithm which computes the similarity. I don't know how to go from A to B.
Not necessarily looking for a real practical solution (which requires a lot of linguistics and phonetics knowledge I think), but looking for a general or high level approach to how I should go about constructing such a similarity function, and how to know what is important and what's not important in its construction.
Here are a few more approaches which ClaudeAI came up with, even one using seemingly complicated tensorflow stuff not just basic handwritten functions. But still, they seem to suffer from the same problems I'm pointing out (which I'm still not sure if those are actually real problems to worry about lol).
